# ReactNative resizeMode: repeat in android not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
imageStyle={{resizeMode: 'contain'}}
```

Am not able to use this props. My intention is to use repeat for the image or image background.
But if I use this am getting error.
"invalid resize method repeat"

ResizeMode contain and stretch work ok for me.

Some one please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you read the docs??

Comment: @KishanGujarati Facebook is planning to bring this for android in their July Release. This issue may fix with version 0.56 which is currently release candidate.

`https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook is planning to bring this for android in their July Release. This issue may fix with version 0.56 which is currently release candidate. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases